# Python - reordering items in list by moving some items to the front while keeping the rest in the same order

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to reorder items in a list in a way illustrated by the following example:

Suppose the list before reordering is:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to implement a method called `reorder_list(list, custom_order)` such that:

```
list1 = reorder_list(list1, [3, 6, 12, 9])
print(list1)

Out: [3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

Explanation: `[3, 6, 12, 9]` is a custom order I am specifying. `12` is not in  `list1` so it will be ignored. `3`,`6`,`9` are in `list1`, so they get moved to the front of the list and their order is the same as in `[3, 6, 12, 9]`. The remaining items in `list1` are after `3`,`6`,`9` and in the original order.

Is there is an easier way (and a Pythonic way) than implementing the C-like loop code. For my purpose I care more about code simplicity than performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reorder_list(items, early):
    moved = [item for item in early if item in items]
    remain = [item for item in items if item not in moved]
    return moved + remain
```

This is really the same algorithm as Gireesh and Stephen Rauch wrote. Gireesh's version is written as it would be before list comprehensions, while Stephen's uses sets for faster lookups (but converts both input lists to sets; one should suffice) and extends with a generator expression instead of allocating a second list.

One thing of note is that we've assumed items are unique within the lists. Both `in` and `set` expect this.

00sdf0's answer uses a very different algorithm that might make sense in Haskell, with its lazy evaluation and tail call optimization, but in this case seems neither easily understood nor performant. It can be more clearly rewritten using slices:

```
def reorder_list(items, early):
    result = list(items)
    for move in reversed(early):
        try:
            place = result.index(move)
            result = [result[place]] + result[:place] + result[place+1:]
        except ValueError:
            pass   # this item wasn't in the list
```

This does allocate more lists, effectively shallow copying the list twice per moved item. Using islice instead of slice produced lazy evaluation that avoided one of those copies.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reorder_list(list_main, custom_order):
    # initializing empty list
    list1 = list()

    # to add values of custom list to list1 which are present in main list
    for value in custom_order:
        # add only the values which are present in main list
        if value in list_main:
            list1.append(value)
    # to add remaining element of main list to list1 which are not present in list1
    for value in list_main:
        if value not in list1:
            list1.append(value)

    return  list1

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list1 = reorder_list(list1, [3,6,12,9])
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of list comprehensions should be reasonably performant for this:

#### Code:

```
def reorder_list(list_to_reorder, custom_order):
    new_list = [x for x in custom_order if x in set(list_to_reorder)]
    new_list.extend(x for x in list_to_reorder if x not in set(custom_order))
    return new_list
```

#### Test Code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(reorder_list(list1, [9, 6, 3, 12]))
```

#### Results:

```
[9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be solved in the following way using `itertools.chain` and `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import chain, islice

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
items_to_move = [9,6,3,12]

# move index i to front of list
def front(seq, i):
    item = islice(seq, i, i+1)
    start = islice(seq, 0, i, None)
    end = islice(seq, i+1, None)
    return list(chain(item,start,end))    

for item in reversed(items_to_move):
    if item in lst:
        lst = front(lst, lst.index(item))
```

Output:

```
[9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```